# Arrow tikz cd don't appear

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

Tikzcd arrows don't appear in my pdf document. Why?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{indentfirst,amsmath,amsfonts,amstext,amssymb,amscd,bezier,amsthm}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}

\usepackage{biocon}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
%\usepackage{pst-grad}
%\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{upgreek}                            % letra grega nao fica em italico
\usepackage{makeidx}                            % ï¿½ndice remissivo \makeindex
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[rm]{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}                  % H insere figura exatamente no local

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% ATALHOS

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}

\usepackage{enumerate,fancyhdr,subfig,multicol,stackrel,framed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

%Operadores
\newcommand{\mdc}{\operatorname{mdc}}
\newcommand{\mmc}{\operatorname{mmc}}
\newcommand{\sen}{\operatorname{sen}}
\newcommand{\tg}{\operatorname{tg}}
\newcommand{\dom}{\operatorname{D}}
\newcommand{\cdom}{\operatorname{CD}}
\newcommand{\ima}{\operatorname{Im}}
\newcommand{\idx}{\operatorname{id}}
\newcommand{\car}{\operatorname{car}}
\newcommand{\irr}{\operatorname{Irr}}
\newcommand{\gal}{\operatorname{Gal}}
\newcommand{\aut}{\operatorname{Aut}}
\newcommand{\oo}{\operatorname{o}}
\newcommand{\Frac}{\operatorname{Frac}}
\newcommand{\Char}{\operatorname{char}}
\newcommand{\norma}{\operatorname{Norma}}
\newcommand{\vt}{\operatorname{\vartheta}}
\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}
\newcommand{\T}{\operatorname{T}}
\newcommand{\N}{\operatorname{N}}
\newcommand{\Ann}{\operatorname{Ann}}
\newcommand{\trdg}{\operatorname{tr.deg.}}
\newcommand{\grau}{\operatorname{grau}}
\newcommand{\suchthat}{\;\ifnum\currentgrouptype=16 \middle\fi|\;}

%Comandos
\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\tf}{\therefore}
\newcommand{\raw}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\lfraw}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\lfaw}{\Leftarrow}

%Letras mathbb
\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb N}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb Z}
\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb C}
\newcommand{\QQ}{\mathbb Q}
\newcommand{\PP}{\mathbb P}
\newcommand{\FF}{\mathbb F}
\newcommand{\Oo}{\mathcal O}
\newcommand{\Uu}{\mathcal U}
\newcommand{\Mm}{\mathcal M}

\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}[teo]{Lema}
\newtheorem{cor}[teo]{Corolário}
\newtheorem{prop}[teo]{Proposição}
\newtheorem{defi}[teo]{Definição}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Exemplo}[chapter]
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercício}[chapter]

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{obs}{Observação}[chapter]

%###########################################################################
%
\font\largefont= pzcmi scaled 3500 \font\numberfont= pzcmi scaled
3000
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  %{\normalfont\Large\sffamily % sans serif
  {\normalfont\Large % roman
  }
  {%\titlerule[3pt]%
   \filright
   \rule[32pt]{.7\linewidth}{4pt}
   \hspace{-8pt}
   \shadowbox{
   \begin{minipage}{.15\linewidth}
     \begin{center}
          \textsl{\bf {\large \chaptertitlename}}\\
       \vspace{1ex}
       {\bf {\numberfont \thechapter}}\\
       \vspace{1ex}
     \end{center}
   \end{minipage}}
  }
  {-10pt}
  {\filcenter
           \sl
           \bf
              \Huge
     }
  [\vspace{-1cm}\singlespacing\hfill\rule{.8\textwidth}{0.5pt}\\
\vskip-2.8ex\hfill\rule{.7\textwidth}{4pt}\onehalfspacing\vspace*{-1ex}]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{*4}{*1}


\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\normalfont\bfseries} {\thesection}{0.5em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
{\normalfont\large\bfseries} {\thesubsection}{0.5em}{}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{1.4\baselineskip}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

%###########################################################################################


%Configuração do tamanho da página e das margens
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}% largura
\setlength{\textheight}{23.5cm}%comprimento
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.7cm}% margem superior
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.5 cm} %margem esquerda


\let\no\operatorname

\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.1 in} \setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23cm} \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.2cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.2cm}

\makeindex                                      % comando para fazer o ï¿½ndice remissivo
\makeatletter
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\tikzset{degil/.style={
            decoration={markings,
            mark= at position 0.5 with {
                  \node[transform shape] (tempnode) {$\backslash$};
                  %\draw[thick] (tempnode.north east) -- (tempnode.south west);
                  }
              },
              postaction={decorate}
}
}

\begin{document}

%Sumário
%\tableofcontents \vspace*{12cm} \thispagestyle{empty}
%\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzcd}
      S_{\RR(x)/\RR}=\{v_{\pi}\mid\pi=x0-a,a\in\RR\;\text{em}\;\pi=(x-c)(x-\overline{c}),c\in\CC,\Im(c)>0\}\cup\{v_{\infty}\}\arrow[leftrightarrow]{d}{\text{bijeção}} & \\
      \text{semiplano superior compactificado}\arrow[leftrightarrow]{r}{\text{bijeção}} & \text{disco com bordo} 
    \end{tikzcd}

%\begin{thebibliography}{99}
%\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [**minimal** working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting interference from the driver specification you gave `graphicx`.  If you get rid of the `dvips` driver specification for the `graphicx` package, your arrows properly appear.

Comment: Another occasion for remarking that the options `dvips` or `pdftex` should *never* be specified with packages such as `graphicx` and `hyperref`.